# How can I suppress output from grep, so that it only returns the exit status?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, grep

I have the `grep` command. I'm searching for a keyword from a file, but I don't want to display the match. I just want to know the exit status of the `grep`.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Any [POSIX compliant version of `grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) has the switch `-q` for quiet:

```
-q
     Quiet. Nothing shall be written to the standard output, regardless
     of matching lines. Exit with zero status if an input line is selected.
```

In GNU grep (and possibly others) you can use long-option synonyms as well:

```
-q, --quiet, --silent     suppress all normal output
```

#### Example

String exists:

```
$ echo "here" | grep -q "here"
$ echo $?
0
```

String doesn't exist:

```
$ echo "here" | grep -q "not here"
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Here is the document from my linux: Normally the exit status is 0 if a line is selected, 1 if no lines were selected, and 2 if an error  occurred.  However,  if  the  -q  or  --quiet or --silent is used and a line is selected, the exit status is 0 even if an error occurred. So there is a subtle difference between using -q and > /dev/null

Answer (score 8):

Just redirect output of `grep` to `/dev/null`:

```
grep sample test.txt > /dev/null

echo $?
```

Comment: This will fail to `echo $?` if `grep` returns a non-zero exit code.

Comment: So `>/dev/null` will just redirect stdout. If you wish to have it completely quiet even on errors, you should do `&>/dev/null`.

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to combine `grep -q <pattern>` with an immediate check of the exit code for last process to quit (`$?`).

You can use this to build up a command like this, for example:

`uname -a | grep -qi 'linux' ;  case "$?" in "0") echo "match" ;; "1") echo "no match" ;; *) echo "error" ;; esac`

You can optionally suppress output from `STDERR` like so:

`grep -qi 'root' /etc/shadow &> /dev/null ;  case "$?" in "0") echo "match" ;; "1") echo "no match" ;; *) echo "error: $?" ;; esac`

This will print `error: 2` from the `case` statement (assuming we do not have privileges to read `/etc/shadow` or that the file does not exist) but the error message from `grep` will be redirected to `/dev/null` so we don't ever see it.